# Cloudbees RUN@Cloud: Could not hook log4j errors

Tags: log4j, cloudbees

On RUN@Cloud I have the following trace from the staxnet startup:

WARNING: Could not hook log4j errors
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at com.staxnet.appserver.jmx.ApplicationObjectFactory$InjectableClassLoader.initClass(ApplicationObjectFactory.java:75)
at com.staxnet.appserver.jmx.ApplicationObjectFactory$InjectableClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationObjectFactory.java:58)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.staxnet.appserver.jmx.ApplicationObjectFactory.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationObjectFactory.java:37)
at com.staxnet.appserver.jmx.ApplicationObjectFactory.createApplicationObject(ApplicationObjectFactory.java:21)
at com.staxnet.appserver.jmx.AppManagementContext.hookLog4JEvents(AppManagementContext.java:60)
at com.staxnet.appserver.jmx.AppManagementContext.onBeforeContextInitialized(AppManagementContext.java:50)
at com.staxnet.appserver.jmx.AppManagementContext.containerEvent(AppManagementContext.java:31)

I understand that it is because I don't have log4j in my application, but this is intentional because we use slf4j+logback which works properly.

It doesn't seem to prevent applications from starting nor functionning, but we cannot add log4j as it conflicts with our logging.
Does this makes us miss some important log coming from the staxnet server?

We have papertrail with notifications and we want to be notified of errors occuring during start-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from cloudbees support:

> Hi Gaspard,
>
> you can safely ignore this error.
>
> This is caused by a platform component that was introduced long time
>   ago trying to better integrate with application logs. Nowadays, we
>   rely on Papertrail add-on for this feature. This is kept on platform
>   to ensure backward compatibility for oldest applications we host.
>
> Nicolas De Loof CloudBees, Inc